# auto-py-to-exe generated 2 error messages: `UPX is not available` and `an error occurred while packaging`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe, upx

I am trying to convert my `.py` to `.exe`.
However, 2 error messages occured while using `auto-py-to-exe`. The first error message was as follows:

```
UPX is not available.
```

The second error message was the following:

```
An error occurred while packaging.
```

This second message was led to 'Project output will not be moved to output folder.
Related errors:

```py
    266710 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.0.dev0
    266725 INFO: Python: 3.9.1
    266746 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
    266765 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESTsoft\CreatorTemp\tmpgijz11tp\Seming Teacher's Reading Master.spec
    266784 INFO: UPX is not available.
    An error occurred while packaging
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 131, in package
        run_pyinstaller()
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
        run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
        PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 725, in main
        build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 669, in build
        code = compile(f.read(), spec, 'exec')
      File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESTsoft\CreatorTemp\tmpgijz11tp\Seming Teacher's Reading Master.spec", line 26
        name='Seming Teacher's Reading Master',
                             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Project output will not be moved to output folder.
```

Answer (score 1):

`UPX` is used to compress your exe further and is optional

> A compressed executable program is wrapped in UPX startup code that dynamically decompresses the program when the program is launched.

Refer to [this](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-upx) for more info on that.

But if you are not concerned about that, then add `--noupx` flag in your command, which will explicitly tell `pyinstaller` to not use it

Now, for the second error, it's caused because of a syntax error in your python file as seen here

```
name='Seming Teacher's Reading Master'
```

you will need to use a higher quotation for the overall string since you have single quote as the part of the string, change it to something like

```
name="Seming Teacher's Reading Master"
```

That should remove the error.